# How to show battery charging status

Tags: java, swt

I need to show that my vehicle is being charged. Charging starts when start button is clicked and stops when stop button is clicked on GUI.

i have a GUI for this work where i have to have some kind of image representation to show the status. (Something like our cell phone battery)

I am using SWT.

Any Suggestion, regarding, how to go about it, will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, then just use the `GC` to draw one or multiple rectangles based on your percentage value. [This](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html) should give you a good starting point.